# How to delete 1 file on 3 files uploaded on vuetify?

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, vue-component, vuetify.js, image-uploading

I read on the docs : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/file-inputs#selection-slot

My code like this :

```
<v-file-input
  v-model="files"
  placeholder="Upload your documents"
  label="File input"
  multiple
  prepend-icon="mdi-paperclip"
>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ text }">
    <v-chip
      small
      label
      color="primary"
    >
      {{ text }}
    </v-chip>
  </template>
</v-file-input>
```

My codepen : https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/vYONqKa?editable=true&editors=101

When upload 3 images and delete, it will delete all images. I want the user to be able to delete 1 image according to his choice. So the user can delete 1 picture

How can I do it?

Answer (score 14):

Configure the chips to delete with a handler method.

- Add 'close' attribute to `v-chip` to get a close button on each file
- Add a handler to the chip, passing index (and text if you want to prompt)
- (optional) remove the clear-all button on VFileInput to prevent user confusion

**Template**

```html
<v-file-input
  ...
  :clearable="false"
>
  <template v-slot:selection="{ index, text }">
    <v-chip
      ...
      close
      @click:close="deleteChip(index, text)"
    >
      {{ text }}
    </v-chip>
  </template>
```

**Component**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    files: [],
  }),
  methods: {
    deleteChip(index, text) {
      // Prompt here with text if required
      this.files.splice(index, 1)
    },
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solutions. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In vuetify 3 Slot selection have:
selection
{
fileNames: string[]
totalBytes: number
totalBytesReadable: string
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).